# How to turn 3D object towards mouse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

I wanted to make a cube (or any other 3D object) rotate towards mouse. Firstly I looked for an answer on StackOverflow and Unity Forums. I discovered plenty of variants that were working, but had some issues - like unexpectedly turning cube around z axis while I moved a mouse, or rotate cube farther than I needed with increasing speed of the mouse. Also I found some of the answers too complex.
So, my goals are:

- to not rotate around z axis;
- to turn exactly where the mouse is;
- to make code short.

Comment: why minuses? did I do something wrong?

Comment: I didn't downvote but my guess is that they didn't find the question informative enough about the problem. Typically when questions come in the form of "I tried x y and z but they didnt work because of p q and r", x, y, and z should be cited specifically to improve the quality of the question. It 1. helps people who have tried x, y, or z find the question easier and 2. is helpful to potential answerers so they know what they need to improve upon.

Comment: thank you for answer, Ruzihm, I think I understand now :) I thought that answering my own question is working like that: I say what I wanted to do and in answer I show how to do it. I will think how to improve question, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still learning scripting and Unity so my answer can be inaccurate or even wrong, but it works for now.

Basically, here's the code:

```
public new Camera camera;
public float depth = 5;

private Vector3 whereIsMyMouse;

void Update()
{
    
   whereIsMyMouse = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(
     Input.mousePosition.x, 
     Input.mousePosition.y, 
     camera.nearClipPlane * depth));
   transform.LookAt(whereIsMyMouse);

}
```

I use `ScreenToWorldPoint()` so Unity can convert Vector2 of the mouse to Vector3 parameter for `LookAt()`.

You can freely assign to `camera` any Camera you need (in Inspector panel in Unity), or you can change code by making variable private and add Camera to it programmatically:

```
private new Camera camera;

void Start()
{
   camera = Camera.main;
}
```

Also you can change `depth` to make turning sharper. As I understand, it changes a `Plane` we're looking from.

To activate script you need to attach it to the object, such as Cube.

Script is working like this:

[image]

Let's add a condition to prevent moving when mouse is out of the window:

```
if ((Input.mousePosition.x < Screen.width 
     && Input.mousePosition.x > 0) 
     && (Input.mousePosition.y < Screen.height 
     && Input.mousePosition.y > 0))
    {
        whereIsMyMouse = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(
          Input.mousePosition.x, 
          Input.mousePosition.y, 
          camera.nearClipPlane * depth));
        transform.LookAt(whereIsMyMouse);
    }
```

I hope it will help someone. Fell free to edit my solution or add yours.

**!EDIT!**

Found out that this solution creates a bug with incorrect rotation. You can fix it by replacing

```
transform.LookAt(whereIsMyMouse);
```

with

```
transform.LookAt(transform.position - whereIsMyMouse);
```

Comment: I think `newClipPlane + depth` would make more sense personally but good stuff.